# How can I speed up a topic model in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, lda, topic-modeling, unsupervised-learning

**Background**
I am trying to fit a topic model with the following data and specification documents=140 000, words = 3000, and topics = 15. I am using the package `topicmodels` in R (3.1.2) on a Windows 7 machine (ram 24 GB, 8 cores). My problem is that the computation only goes on and on without any “convergence” being produced.

I am using the default options in `LDA()` function in `topicmodels`:

*Run model*

```
dtm2.sparse_TM <- LDA(dtm2.sparse, 15)
```

The model has been running for about 72 hours – and still is as I am writing.

**Question**
 So, my questions are (a) if this is normal behaviour; (b) if not to the first question, do you have any suggestion on what do; (c) if yes to the first question, how can I substantially improve the speed of the computation?

**Additional information**: The original data contains not 3000 words but about 3.7 million. When I ran that (on the same machine) it did not converge, not even after a couple of weeks. So I ran it with 300 words and only 500 documents (randomly selected) and not all worked fine. I used the same nr of topics and default values as before for all models.

So for my current model (see my question) I removed sparse terms with the help of the tm package.

*Remove sparse terms*

```
dtm2.sparse <- removeSparseTerms(dtm2, 0.9)
```

Thanks for the input in advance
Adel

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *online* variational Bayes which can easily handle the training such number of documents. In online variational Bayes you train the model using mini-batches of your training samples which increases the convergence speed amazingly (refer to SGD link below).

For R, you can use this [package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i13). [Here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v040i13/v40i13.pdf) you can read more about it and how to use it too. Also look at [this](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3902-online-learning-for-latent-dirichlet-allocation.pdf) paper since that R package implements the method used in that paper. If possible, import their Python code uploaded [here](https://github.com/Blei-Lab/onlineldavb) in R. I highly recommend the Python code since I had such a great experience with it for a project I recently worked on. When the model is learned, you can save the topic distributions for future use and use the input it to `onlineldavb.py` along with your test samples to integrate over the topic distributions given those unseen documents. With online variational Bayesian methods I trained an LDA with 500000 documents and 5400 words in the vocabulary data set in less than 15 hours.

**Sources**

> - [Variational Bayesian Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_Bayesian_methods)
> - [Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent)

Comment: Has anyone integrated the online variational bayes python LDA model with their R dataframes to generate topics?

Comment: @CelesteManu I'm not sure about that. Sorry